# How to get index number from a Terraform Loop

Tags: for-loop, terraform

In terraform, we can do loop inside the locals block as shown in the example below. I need to get the current loop index/sequence number and save it under flattened_content.loop_index_number.

The file.yaml content

```
org:
  ou:
    InternalClient:
      - InternalClient1
      - InternalClient2
    Client:
      - Client1
      - Client2
```

The terraform code

```
locals {
  config_path   = "file.yaml"
  file_content   = yamldecode(file(local.config_path))
  ou_contents = local.file_content.org.ou
  flattened_content = flatten([
    for client_department, client_list in local.ou_contents : [
      for client in client_list : {
        client_department_name = client_department # Ex. InternalClient, Client
        client_name = client
        1st_level_loop_index_number = <???>
        2nd_level_loop_index_number = <???>
      }
    ]
  ])   
}
```

Please provide the code how to get the current loop index/sequence number in Terraform both 1st and 2nd level loop index number.

Answer (score 3):

The loops provide the index by default, you just add a variable, e.g. called `current_index`, to the loop:

```
for current_index, client in client_list:
```

and `current_index` will be 0,1,2,...

Comment: How about  the 1st level loop index number? i.e. local.ou_contents level. TIA